# Visualize graph in Java easiest way

Tags: java, graph, graph-visualization

I have a dataset that looks like that:

A: B,C,D
B: A,C
C: A,B
D: A
E: /NULL/

(A-E refers to the graph vertexes)

I would like to export this data structure to .png, or visualize in .xhtml file for example. The most important, that I want to this very simple and easy way. I would glad to see some sample code in the API or somewhere.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to look into setting individual pixels of a BufferedImage as described here and then saving it as .png: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/graphics/bufferedimage_setrgb.shtml

Comment: There are a few visual graphing libraries in Java, have you found and tried to use one?

Comment: Graphviz will give you a lovely .png of a graph.  Java need not always be the answer.

Comment: I need to do this in Java, because data input comes from program code and I need to export it every second.
I searched libraries in Java, but there are plenty of them and I don't know which is the best for me.